# replace NULL value with an empty string Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Is there any way I can replace the `null` value displayed with an empty string in vue?

```
<template>
<div class="flexItem">
      <ui-textbox label="Address" v-model="customer.address"
          :disabled="disabled"
          name="address"
          @input="update()"
          v-validate="'max:255'"
      ></ui-textbox>
</div>
</template>

export default{
name: 'customer',
props:{
    value:{
        type:Object,
        required:true,
    },
    disabled:{
        type:Boolean,
        default:false,
    }
},
data(){
    return {
        customer:{
            address:"",
        }
    },
methods:{
    update(){
        this.$emit('input',this.customer);
    },
}
```

And the display value now is `null`, but I want it to be replaced with empty string.[image]

Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: can you share live example

Comment: @C2486 I'm afraid I can't for I have to fetch it from database.

Comment: is that ui-textbox a component belonging to any third party library? I mean [this](https://josephuspaye.github.io/Keen-UI/#/ui-textbox), for example.

Comment: @P3trur0 No, it's not. I have my own `Textbox.vue` file which I use on other pages.

Comment: @ramedju could please share also its source code, then?

Comment: @P3trur0 What source code you mean?

Comment: @P3trur0 Updated.

Comment: @P3trur0 OOooopppsss, apologies for the confusions, but we are using `keen-ui` same as what you've sampled. I've misunderstood your statement .

Comment: I tried to make work your code , you can go ahead with

Comment: @ramedju please try to focus on how you bind data to that submittedValue in Textbox.vue. Could you please show that part of your source code too?

Answer (score 2):

I think this will oblige you to dump v-model and to code the two sides of your binding separately. So...

```
<ui-textbox 
    :value="customer.address || ''" 
    @input="customer.address = event.target.value"
    ...
```

Comment: Tried but still the same. Updated my question with the `@input` event.

Comment: Neither it should be `v-model` for any component nor `:value` it should bind the param to make it as data for child component , here `ui-textbox`

Comment: [Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/bbsimonbb/z463ertm/2/) a jsfiddle using a normal input type text. Null never displays. Could you check that the null you are seeing really is a null? It could be just the word null inside quotes in your JSON?

Comment: @bbsimonbb In my database table, value is `NULL`.

Comment: yup, but what happens to it along the road? In javascript, `null !== "null"`

Comment: `!!"null" === true`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `Null` because its not properly binding up with child component .Neither it should be `v-model` for any component nor `:value` it should bind the param to make it as data for child component , here `ui-textbox`
.As I commented to share live demo like this, Try like this to make work your code

```js
Vue.component('ui-text', {
 template:`<div><input type="text" v-model="customer.name "/>
      <input type="text" v-model="customer.address" /></div>`,
  props:["customer"],
  data(){
    return {
        customer:{
            name:"",
            address:"",
        }
    }
  }
});
Vue.component('mycomp', { 
template: 
`<div>
All Records
<div class="flexItem">
      <div class="row" v-for="customer in customers"><ui-text :customer="customer"></ui-text></div>
</div>
</div>`,
  props:["customers"],
data(){
    return {
        customers:[{
            name:"",
            address:"",
        }]
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    customers: [{name:'test1',address:'new address1'},{name:'test2',address:'new address2'},{name:'test3',address:'new address3'}],
  }
})
```

```css
.flexItem{
  border:2px solid green;
  padding:10px;
}
.row{
  border:1px solid red;
  margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>

<div id="app">
<mycomp :customers="customers"></mycomp>
{{customers}}
</div>
```

Comment: Apologies. just my screen not that wide. There's no error. Gotta study this one.

Comment: Got an error when I set use the `props["customers"]`. Error: `app.js:28014 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': 'props:[customers],' is not a valid attribute name.`

Comment: You don't have `customers` you have `customer`, use code according to your requirement and attributes.

Comment: In my code above, where I should insert in my `flexitem` class? Coz it throws the same error even though I use my own attribute.

Comment: Can you share your code which gives you error ? Or live demo ?